# Removing boldface from appendix chapters in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, appendices, bold

How do I remove boldface from appendix chapter headings in the TOC?

I would like the TOC to look like this:

> **1 First chapter**
>     1.1 First section
>   **Appendices**
>   Appendix I First appendix
>   Appendix II Second appendix

My MWE looks like this:

```
    \documentclass{report}
    \usepackage[toc,page,titletoc]{appendix}

    \begin{document}
    \tableofcontents

    \chapter{First chapter}
    \section{First section}

    \begin{appendices}
    \chapter{First appendix}
    \chapter{Second appendix}
    \end{appendices}
    \end{document}
```

and returns

> **1 First chapter**
>     1.1 First section
>   **Appendices**
>   **Appendix I First appendix**
>   **Appendix II Second appendix**

I've looked through the [`titlesec`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) and [`appendix`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/appendix/appendix.pdf) packages but can't see the options, and the solution doesn't appear on Stack Exchange as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An appropriately-placed patch in the ToC can correct this behaviour. Below I've patched `\l@chapter` - the macro responsible for setting the `chapter`-related content in the ToC - and removed `\bfseries`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[toc,page,titletoc]{appendix}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\appendices{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\patchcmd{\protect\l@chapter}{\bfseries}{}{}{}}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}

\begin{appendices}
\chapter{First appendix}
\chapter{Second appendix}
\end{appendices}
```

The process is automated by adding the patch to `\begin{appendices}`. That way you don't have to clutter your document with such code.

Comment: This is excellent, exactly what I needed! Thank you.