# Romove boldface from chapter names of appendices in toc Latex

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex, appendices

I want to unbold the chapter name of the appendices in the toc, and only keep the appendix title/numbering bold. For example: "**Appendix A** supplementary materials for chapter 5". I used the solution from here [Removing boldface from appendix chapters in TOC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316384/removing-boldface-from-appendix-chapters-in-toc). I thought I could apply the unbold function to titletoc, but it doesn't work.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\appendices{%
  \addtocontents{titletoc}{\protect\patchcmd{\protect\l@chapter}{\bfseries}{}{}{}}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\begin{appendices}

\chapter{Supplementary materials for Chapter 5}
\chapter{Supplementary materials for Chapter 6}

\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

[image: This is the original complied result]

[image: This is the result I intended to achieve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
% apptocprob.tex  SE 589103
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}

\begin{comment}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\appendices{%
  \addtocontents{titletoc}{\protect\patchcmd{\protect\l@chapter}{\bfseries}{}{}{}}
}
\makeatother
\end{comment}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First}

\begin{appendices}
%%% non-bold titles
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect
\renewcommand{\protect\cftchapaftersnumb}{\normalfont}
}
%%% non-bold page numbers
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect
\renewcommand{\protect\cftchappagefont}{\normalfont}
}

\chapter{Supplementary materials for Chapter 5}
\chapter{Supplementary materials for Chapter 6}

\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works perfectly!!! thank you ;D